# Switches not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my script I have the following:

```
DEBUG="false"
while getopts ":d:" opt; do
      case $opt in
        d)
          $BIN_ECHO -e "DEBUG MODE ENABLED WITH $OPTARG" >&2
          DEBUG="YES"
          ;;
        \?)
          $BIN_ECHO -e "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
          exit 1
          ;;
        :)
          $BIN_ECHO -e "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
          exit 1
          ;;
      esac
    done
```

However, everytime I run it, the DEBUG=false does not seem to be taking priority.

I have this for example:

```
if [ $DEBUG=="YES" ]; then
    $BIN_ECHO -e "SETTING LOCATION TO /USR/SRC"
fi
cd /usr/src
```

Even if I do not use the -d on the script, it will still run like it is in debug mode. Any idea why?

Comment: Where is `DEBUG` var being used in script? Is this your full script?

Comment: These are the main parts of the script. I am declaring DEBUG at the top of the script as FALSE and then I am setting it to TRUE with the FLAG -d and checking to see if it is TRUE with the IF statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `if [ $DEBUG=="YES" ]; then` is incorrect. You need spaces around the `==`.

Like so `if [ $DEBUG == "YES" ]; then`.

The way you have it all smushed together means `[` only sees **one** argument and a single argument to `[`/`test` is interpreted as `[ -n word ]` which is testing for a non-empty string (which `==YES` is regardless of what the value of `$DEBUG` is.

That all being said, you aren't using the argument to `-d` anywhere and you should probably pick one of `false`/`true` or `yes`/`no` as your pairing.

Answer (score 2):

You've made a spacing mistake. What the test is testing is:

```
if [ false==YES ] ; then
```

Remember that the shell expands variables before executing a command. So what you've done is equivalent to

```
if [ any_old_random_string_with==in_it ]
```

...which will always evaluate to "true", and it gives you the behavior you see.

You simply need to do:

```
if [ "$DEBUG" == "YES" ] ; then
```

Comment: The issue isn't so much when parameter expansion occurs as the fact that `=` doesn't signal the start of a new argument. The `test` command (i.e., `[`) doesn't parse `false==YES` as an expression, it takes three separate arguments `false`, `==`, `YES`, then notes that when it receives 3 arguments, the second one is interpreted as an operator used to compare the first and third.

Answer (score 1):

The `getopts` usage is wrong in the script.

`getopts ":d:" opt`

the `:` following the `d` indicates that a value is passed along with the option `-d` as

`./yourscript -d value`

which is not the case. drop the `:` as

`getopts ":d" opt`

```
DEBUG="false"
while getopts ":d" opt; do
      case $opt in
        d)
          $BIN_ECHO -e "DEBUG MODE ENABLED WITH $OPTARG" >&2
          DEBUG="YES"
          ;;
        \?)
          $BIN_ECHO -e "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
          exit 1
          ;;
        :)
          $BIN_ECHO -e "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
          exit 1
          ;;
      esac
    done
```

calling the script with `-d` option

`./yourscript -d`

will now produce output as

```
DEBUG MODE ENABLED WITH 
SETTING LOCATION TO /USR/SRC
```